# Multibranch pipeline job not showing open pull requests

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have configured a multibranch pipeline job in Jenkins linked to our GitHub repo which is working nicely, feeding back the status of checks to the pull request in our GitHub so we know if the branch is good for merging in.

What I don't see are any open pull requests listed against the Job in Jenkins:

[image]

We also have the Blue Ocean plugin in installed and no PR's are shown there either.

Anyone know why this is the case? Am I missing another plugin\config?

Comment: I have the same problem. Scan Repository does detect the pull request but no Job is created. I tried what @burnettk suggested but without success. The Pull request is detect - I see it in the "scan repository log" - but no Job is created.

Answer (score 24):

I had this issue as well. I tried what joey suggested, but that did not work. I found out that if you add `PR-.+` (or `PR-*` as a wildcard) to your regex filter for branches to include, the pull requests "magically" appear. The documentation of this was found [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003019232-GitHub-Webhook-Pipeline-Multibranch). It's very frustrating that the "official" documentation for this plugin does not explain this (at least from what sparse documentation I could find). The configuration for my project, which works, is here:
[image: Picture.Jenkins.MultiBranch.Pipeline.PullRequests.addTo.Github.FilterDiscover.And.BlueOcean.png]

I'm not sure if this is a recommended way to use this plugin for this use case, but Jenkins never seems to have ample documentation.

Comment: re magic constant word PR-*, which are not the name of our branches nor the name of the url for github for a pull : I found this explanation: "  the name of the PR (which will always be PR-... unless the SCMSource uses a different prefix for its change request concept (wink))" on Changelog for Version 2.2.4 (Nov 2, 2017) https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCM+API+Plugin

Comment: Thank you!  This is why I love stackoverflow.  So obvious, of course there was a second list of magic identifiers, that only correspond to the internal Pull Request ID on Bitbucket.  So obvious in hindsight.  You just saved me a lot of pain!

Comment: In my case adding ```PR-*``` regex did not work for some of the pipelines. Removing the filter itself let PR be shown on the list. This is just FYI. I do not encourage this path.

Comment: I used Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin, and it turned out I had to add `pull-requests/*/from` in Branch Sources > Add > Discover other refs, and if you are using `Filter by name (with regular expression)` then you will have to append `|pull-requests-.*` to it.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue. But this time within Blue Ocean UI as shown below

[image]

The fix was to switch from using Git to GitHub Branch Source at the job level and configure GitHub Branch Source. The job type was Multibranch pipeline.

Comment: Why would I create an entirely new question when the context of the question I was trying to have answer is in this same post? Besides, I ended up answering my own question, so there was really not point ever in me removing my post.

Comment: Why would you create an entirely new question? Because it *is* an entirely new question. It's definitely not an answer. But now that you've edited into an answer, all is fine

Comment: The fix for the author is the same fix for me. Therefore, the fix should be contained here. Otherwise we are just creating duplicates lol. Also, if we could post images into comments, that would be nice.

Comment: I am also having this problem in blue ocean. I created the job with the "GitHub Organization" type which scans a github organisation. Everything else works except the pull request page. Did you still need to install the github pull request builder plugin?

Comment: Yes I definitely had that pluggin  installed as well when it was working for me. again, the only issue was the job level configuration

Comment: This does not seem to work form me :(
I am using the "GitHub Organization" job jype. Is that the job type you mean? Where are you changing your settings?

Comment: The author for this particular post was having problems with "Multibranch Pipeline" job type. This allows a job to be configured with github repository and build/deploy on checkin, etc

Comment: Ah. I missed the job type in the title. Thanks for pointing it out. Blue ocean seemed to create using the "GitHub Organization" job type automatically. I will see if i can swap it. If not, i'll start a new stackoverflow question... i bit silly to hijack this one :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause could be that GitHub is unable to connect to Jenkins directly due to a firewall. This is likely the case if GitHub never reports the status check as completed, in other words, it hangs forever.

In this case, polling is an easy solution. Go to `http://_jenkins_ip_:8080/job/_job_name_/configure` and select the "Scan Repository Triggers" tab. Tick the "Periodically if not otherwise run" checkbox and select an interval. I have 15 minutes on mine.

The first time this is done, there should be an immediate scan and it should detect the pull request, otherwise, there might be something else going on. Check the "Scan Repository Log" page on the job, as it might have useful info.

By the way, I did not install the "GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin" as the page says that it has a security issue. Instead, the "GitHub Branch Source Plugin" is being used. Some other related plugins installed:

```
Git client plugin
Git plugin
GitHub API Plugin
GitHub Authentication plugin
GitHub Integration Plugin
GitHub plugin
```

I'm also using Blue Ocean, but this is not required, it simply provides a different UI.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old topic, but I had the same issue while I was trying to visualize my Pull Requests from Bitbucket and I hope this answer will help other people in need. In my case, I was using Bitbucket Push and Pull Request Plugin, which is pretty similar to other GitHub Plugins for Jenkins.
My problem came from the fact that I selected **Git** instead of **Bitbucket** in **Branch Sources >> Add Source** section. I suspect the same thing happened in this case, where the two options **Git** and **GitHub** are even easier to confuse.